# unable to import maven project into Intellij Idea :looking for available profile

Tags: intellij-idea

I have set maven home directory , User setting file and local repo  in Idea.

Then I import a maven project ,it starts to scan mavne projects, looking for available profiles. and I can see the Progress bar. but it takes a long time and  back to the first step again.

Is my setting wrong ? how to import a maven project into IDEA?  thanks a lot !

Comment: Do you use Maven 3? Does it help if you enable Maven 3 option in Settings | Maven | Import? Any exceptions in [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446)? Does command line `mvn install` work without problems?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same Problem. The solution was to edit the `/etc/hosts` file and add at the first line:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost
```

See also:

[Unable to import Maven project into IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701347/unable-to-import-maven-project-into-intellij-idea)

Comment: also do not have any other ip´s resolved to localhost.

Comment: Sorry but where do I find /etc/hosts

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.

Comment: This is the solution

Comment: @Adam Goldberg On Windows it's `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: For windows(10 and 11)-it's at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts But even after doing that and restarting the system  - I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For windows(10 and 11)-it's at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
But even after doing that and restarting the system - I am facing the same issue.

I have dual boot linux(Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS). Switched to Linux and without making any changes, everything worked like charm. Same IntelliJ version.