# IntelliJ Stuck "Scanning Maven Projects"

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I just freshly installed IntelliJ Community Edition. When I try to import a Maven project, it gets stuck on the step "Scanning Maven Projects" and says its reading ".../pom.xml". It holds here for about 10 minutes, quits out of this window, and then doesn't import the projects at all.

Some other posts have recommended setting up /etc/hosts file, but mine is already set up with 127.0.0.1 localhost. I've set up the proxy information in IntelliJ and in my .m2/settings.xml file as well.

Any suggestions on how I can get IntelliJ just to open up my project?

Best,
Keren

Comment: can you post the pom.xml of the project you are trying to import? and the relevant part  ( proxy and central repo) of the settings.xml

Comment: I just figured it out, it was complaining about the pom.xml but the pom.xml wasn't the actual problem. It was the /etc/hosts file that was throwing the problem. If you map more one value to "localhost" then IntelliJ freaked out for me for some reason. So I uncommented ::1 localhost in my /etc/hosts file and it worked.

Comment: I modified the etc/hosts file the other day which caused the issue . 
If you have  127.0.0.1       localhost in your etc/hosts, use are good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to import maven project into Intellij Idea :looking for available profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981224/unable-to-import-maven-project-into-intellij-idea-looking-for-available-profile)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473138/cant-import-the-maven-project-in-intellij-idea-2016-1-1/52519992#52519992

Answer (score 12):

Already answered here [unable to import maven project into Intellij Idea :looking for available profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981224/unable-to-import-maven-project-into-intellij-idea-looking-for-available-profile)

> The solution was to edit the /etc/hosts file and add at the first line:
>
> 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost

**Also, make sure *localhost* is mapped only once.**

(answered in the comments. I am just leaving this answer for reference as it's one of Google's first results when searching for this problem)

Comment: Do you have any idea why IntelliJ is behaving like that. It seems weird