# IntelliJ Idea cannot connect to plugins

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I try to build a Jenkins plugin with IntelliJ Idea and i get the following errors and I can't compile it. 
It complains that it can't reconnect to plugins.

Any idea what's going on?

[image]

LE:

Here is the message:

[image]

Comment: What message do you see when you hover over red lines?

Comment: I've attached a image with the errors.

Comment: Have a look at this question: [unable-to-import-maven-project-into-intellij-idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701347/unable-to-import-maven-project-into-intellij-idea)

Comment: I already have 127.0.0.1 localhost in hosts file and also tried the -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true option and still no success.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already used the IPv4 option, try the other solutions from this article [Network Connectivity Issues When Running Under Java 1.7](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23403071-Network-connectivity-issues-when-running-under-Java-1-7) (copied here for future reference):

- Add -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true into the list of the IDE JVM options. If you are using IPv6 only network, specify -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true option.
- On Windows run netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable to resolve FTP connection issues.
- Agnitum Outpost Security Suite and some other firewalls may block even localhost connections, disabling firewall may not help, only uninstalling the firewall will resolve the problem.
- If nothing above helps, try running the IDE under JDK 1.6 instead.