# Maven project won't compile after upgrade to Intellij 13.1 from 12

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

My code no longer compiles after the upgrade.  Imports from libraries that are included as maven dependencies show compile issue with Cannot resolve symbol.  I have Invalidated the cache and restarted Intellij.  I have cleared .m2/repository and watched Intellij repull in the dependencies.  Pulling in the dependencies seems to work fine, but then fail to get loaded is my guess.

In my Idea log I see the following exceptions:

```
2014-03-20 14:04:49,587 [  27517]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager). 
2014-03-20 14:04:49,588 [  27518]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. 
2014-03-20 14:04:49,588 [  27518]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info. 
2014-03-20 14:04:53,009 [  30939]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Cannot reconnect. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:98)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.resolveProject(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.resolveProject(MavenProjectReader.java:462)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProject.resolve(MavenProject.java:587)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.resolve(MavenProjectsTree.java:1215)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessorResolvingTask.perform(MavenProjectsProcessorResolvingTask.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.doProcessPendingTasks(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:131)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.access$100(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:28)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor$2.run(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:107)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil$6.run(MavenUtil.java:440)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
    java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuildingResult
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:227)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.resolveProject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$2$1$1.compute(RemoteUtil.java:106)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:167)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$2$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.resolveProject(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper$4.execute(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:100)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper$4.execute(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:89)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuildingResult
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1333)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1895)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1895)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1895)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:225)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuildingResult
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1165)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1413)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:422)
    at java.lang.Throwable.writeObject(Throwable.java:652)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:950)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1482)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1413)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:422)
    at java.lang.Throwable.writeObject(Throwable.java:652)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:950)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1482)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1413)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:329)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:341)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
2014-03-20 14:07:29,757 [ 187687]   INFO - ellij.vfs.persistent.FSRecords - Creating VFS corruption marker; Trace=
java.lang.Exception
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.createBrokenMarkerFile(FSRecords.java:193)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.access$2700(FSRecords.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.invalidateCaches(FSRecords.java:1613)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.InvalidateCachesAction.actionPerformed(InvalidateCachesAction.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:261)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:923)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:231)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:104)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:291)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:389)
    at com.apple.laf.ScreenMenuItemCheckbox.itemStateChanged(ScreenMenuItemCheckbox.java:178)
    at java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem.processItemEvent(CheckboxMenuItem.java:372)
    at java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem.processEvent(CheckboxMenuItem.java:340)
    at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEventImpl(MenuComponent.java:343)
    at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEvent(MenuComponent.java:331)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Best contact IntelliJ support.

Comment: It seems to be related to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116482

Comment: had a similar problem the built in maven did not like my project. using a downloaded maven 3 worked. changed `home directory` under `build tools -> maven`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Disable the Maven 3 checkbox in "Settings | Maven | Importing".

Comment: Any explanation why this happens?

Answer (score 5):

Invalidate your Idea cache and restart Idea.

Comment: how to invalidate cache?

Comment: `File` --> `Invalidate Cache`.

Comment: Did you restart Idea?

Comment: yep I made the invalidate and restart thing

Comment: Fixed it for me in 13.1.4.

Comment: You lifesaver! Worked in CE 2020.2 on a Macbook for me. Brilliant.

Answer (score 4):

In my case **Cannot reconnect** error was caused by absence of class **DependencyTreeResolutionListener** as `idea.log` states. I've noticed that library containing this class is absent in maven3 plugin but present in maven2. So I copied `maven-dependency-tree-1.2.jar` from `<IdeaInstallDir>/plugins/maven/lib/maven2` to `<IdeaInstallDir>/plugins/maven/lib/maven3`. Then I updated current maven project by pushing *Reimport All Maven Projects* button in *Maven Projects* tool window. After that error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) > Maven > Importing > JDK for importer: Use JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

For me, increasing Maven's allocated memory worked:

Settings -> Maven -> Runner > VM Options :
-Xms128m -Xmx512m

Answer (score 0):

Change the 'JDK for importer' found under File--> Settings --> Build, Execution and Deployment --> Build Tools --> Maven --> Importing to 'Use JAVA_HOME'