# how to deal with that pom.xml shows a red- line under <project>

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

the label  shows

```
org/apache/maven/shared/dependency/tree/DependencyTreeResolutionListener*.
```

There are some clues:first,Event log shows 
 `Auto build completed with errors`,second,Problems show Error:`Maven Resources Compiler: Maven project configuration required for module 'ddd' isn't available. Compilation of Maven projects is supported only if external build is started from an IDE.`

Comment: I really need your help!Thank you!

Comment: can you share your dependency i.e. pom

Comment: and project structure with all modules

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543064/maven-project-wont-compile-after-upgrade-to-intellij-13-1-from-12/25194228#25194228 Make sure you are using bundled Maven in IDE Maven settings. Also my be a corrupted installation. Re-install from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download into a new empty directory.

Comment: First try to build your project on plain command line. I suppose it will not work...

Comment: ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>HAHA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>```