# idea maven cannot reconnect

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I use `IDEA` to import Maven project, I get the error `Cannot reconnect`,the log message is:

```
    2019-11-25 15:06:55,529 [15756924]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Cannot reconnect. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.performCancelable(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:98)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.resolveProject(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.resolveProject(MavenProjectReader.java:494)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doResolve(MavenProjectsTree.java:1301)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.resolve(MavenProjectsTree.java:1273)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessorResolvingTask.perform(MavenProjectsProcessorResolvingTask.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.doProcessPendingTasks(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.access$000(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:32)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor$2.run(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:109)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.lambda$runInBackground$5(MavenUtil.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start maven service; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:169)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:74)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$2.create(MavenServerManager.java:375)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$2.create(MavenServerManager.java:364)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.lambda$resolveProject$5(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.performCancelable(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:89)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:338)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:112)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.lambda$acquire$2(RemoteProcessSupport.java:245)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClassLoaderUtil.runWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderUtil.java:66)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:227)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:243)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:149)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:166)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 32 more
```

I tried to change the `host` file `127.0.0.1 localhost`, but nothing changes.

I find the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615067/intellij-idea-maven-cannot-reconnect-error), but our error message is different.

Comment: Are you connected to internet ?

Comment: It looks like you have a firewall or similar configured not to allowed to localhost: `Connection refused: connect`..